# Nested Data Validation Lists with Same List of Names

Tags: excel

I have three data validation lists, which share the same list of names. Let's call them Name1, Name2 and Name3. Now I need to build these three data validation drop down menu in a hierarchical structure. Like, if I choose Name1 in the first data validation list, then in the second list there will only be Name2 and Name3 in there, and then I choose Name2 in the second list, there will only be Name3 in the third list. What approach can I achieve this? Should I use vba in this case or there is any other way?

Comment: Does every row have these data validation drop downs and do the drop-down lists need to exclude selected items on a per-row basis? Or are these drop-downs a one-time thing?

Comment: @tigeravatar, the first situation.

Comment: While it is possible to do this, it would be much easier to just use conditional formatting to highlight duplicates in a row.

Comment: @tigeravatar, I would prefer to do this other than using conditional formatting. So does this mean I need to use vba?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the results you want, the answer is deceptively complex.  I'm going to show how it's done, but I'm not really going to go in depth for why it works, because it is very advanced and if you're looking for that kind of education, Stack Overflow isn't the place.

So first things first, let's get our workbook setup.  In my example workbook for this scenario, I have two sheets.  The first sheet I've left named `Sheet1` and the second is named `Lists`.  Sheet1 contains the data validation drop down cells starting in row 2 because row 1 is a header row.  It should like this (and what the drop downs will look like when everything is done, so show that it works):

[image: Sheet1 screenshot]

The Lists sheet should have the list of names in column A, again starting in row 2 because row 1 is a header row.  We will be using a dynamic named range for the full list of names, I named it `listNames` and it is defined with this formula:

```
=Lists!$A$2:INDEX(Lists!$A:$A,MAX(2,ROWS(Lists!$A:$A)-COUNTBLANK(Lists!$A:$A)))
```

Next we need to generate, per row, the remaining names that haven't been chosen in that row on Sheet1.  To start, in cell C2 and down is simply the row number.  This doesn't need to be here, but it makes it easier for us to manually reference and make sure its working properly.  In cell D2 and copied over and down is this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(listNames,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF(Sheet1!$A2:$C2,listNames)=0)*(COUNTIF($C2:C2,listNames)=0),),0)),"")
```

I copied it over to column I, which works for this example.  To make it suit your actual data, make sure its copied over to a number of columns that equals the number of items in your complete list.  Because there are only three names, I only needed to copy it over 3 columns (D:F), but this shows it can go over and that's fine.  It must be copied over a minimum number of columns equaling the total number of items in column A.  I also copied down for each row that contains the data validation cells in Sheet1.  In my example workbook, I copied it down 15 rows, so it goes from row 2 to 16, and looks like this:

[image: Lists sheet screenshot]

Notice that because Name2 and Name3 were selected in row 2 of Sheet1, the formula only returns Name1 on row 2 because it is the only remaining name.  and for rows 3 and 4, because only Name1 was selected, Name2 and Name3 are the only ones shown for those rows.

The next step is another dynamic named range formula.  This one is tricky because we want it to look at the *active row* instead of the entire dataset.  This is accomplished by leaving out the absolute reference symbol `$` on the row numbers.  So on the `Lists` sheet, select cell D2.  **YOU MUST HAVE CELL D2 SELECTED FOR THIS** (technically you can select any cell, but then copy/pasting the named range formula will fail, adjust it to match whatever row you currently have selected) and create a new named range, I named this one `listRemaining` and it is defined with this formula:

```
=Lists!$D2:INDEX(Lists!$D2:$IV2,0,MAX(1,COLUMNS(Lists!$D2:$IV2)-COUNTBLANK(Lists!$D2:$IV2)))
```

Lastly is to create the actual data validation cells.  Select the cells you want to contain the drop-down lists and make them a Data Validation List and set the Source to `=listRemaining`

[image: Data Validation screenshot]

And voilà!  You now have the dynamic drop-down lists you're looking for (as shown in the first image).

I hope this helps you and that you are able to adjust it to suit your actual data.

Example workbook: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz-nM5djZBWYNGotU3ZleEk1bk0

Comment: Wow. This is incredible. Thanks! However, it is a little bit difficult for me to digest. One questions is, before I define the dynamic name list, should I build data validation lists on sheet1? If yes, should I build it only in cell A2? or B2 and C2 as well?

Comment: @JosephLin No, setting the data validation is the last step.  I only showed it in image one to present what the finished product will look like.

Comment: So let me sort out the correct processes. First, I define the name in Lists using the first formula. Then after building the Row column, which I won't really be using in further executions, I drop the second formula in cell D2 in Lists and copy it to column E and F. And during the previous step, I don't have to mind sheet1, right? Next, by using the last formula and select cell D2, I define another dynamic name before setting up those three data validation lists. And that's it? But now I only have two define names, how can I assign them to three data validations?

Comment: And I am not sure what you meant by mentioning copying the second formula to Column I in Lists. Sorry, I am a little confused here, please walk me through processes slowly. Thanks!

Comment: @JosephLin Set the data validation list source to `=listRemaining` for *all* cells that will contain the data validation.  There is no need for additional named ranges.  Everything you need is in the answer.  Like I said, this is a very complex thing to do, and I have explained the steps necessary to perform this.

Comment: Hi, @tigeravatar, one more question. Now that my data validations are on the 4th row, so I changed the row number in the second formula. And now the problem I encountered here s that when I try to used the second defined dynamic name as the list for the data validation, it tells me it has to be a list, and the name that I define is a comma delimited range. I tried it in the example you put here, it didn't happen

Comment: @JosephLin If you are going to change the row number, make sure that the selected cell is in **the same row as the row number** for the second formula.  This is important because it is not an absolute reference, so it has to match the *active row*.

Comment: So I change `$A2:$C2` to `$A4:$C4` and I also change row number of Column C in Lists, starting from 4, Am I correct here?

Comment: The row numbers in column C are simply there for reference.  And no, they shouldn't be changed.  This is because those items are linked directly to their rows.  So if you make a change in row 4, it will be reflected in row 4,  regardless of what number is in C.  You could have blanks in column C and it won't affect the outcome, because those numbers are only for our reference.

Comment: Basically, just delete the contents (not the entire row) of the formulas in rows 2 and 3 so that the formulas in column D and over start at row 4

Comment: I cleared the content in row 2 and 3, left row 2 and 3 blank. And I keep the defining formula the same, leaving it starting with D2. But the excel still wouldn't let me use it as the list in data validations.

Comment: @JosephLin here is a link to an example workbook you can play with: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz-nM5djZBWYNGotU3ZleEk1bk0